# How to connect to an Oracle database using odbcDriverConnect

Tags: r

I need to use odbcDriverConnect  to connect to an Oracle database and I CANNOT odbcCConnect so i have to provide a Driver parameter but I am not sure what it should be. Here is my current call to the odbcDriverConnect() function

```
odbcDriverConnect("Driver=??????;server=myServer;database=mydatabase;uid=me;pwd=mypassword;port=1234")
```

What driver should I put in so I can query the database?

Thank you.

Comment: Driver and dsn are specific to your machine and your db. There's no way anyone not sitting at your computer would know.

Comment: But can you give an example or tell me where I can find out on my machine what the driver should be?

Comment: I'm not going to be able to provide any information that isn't in the (excellent) RODBC vignette, especially since you haven't even said what platform you're on.

Comment: My Driver is OraClient12Home1

Comment: which vignette is that? I on windows 7

Comment: [This vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/vignettes/RODBC.pdf) you find [on this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html).